# Visual Studio 2010 new C++ project from existing code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to modify an existing project but put all the source and header files etc. into a new directory to keep them separate.  When I use the "create new project from existing code" option, the solution files seem to point back to my original .cpp file which I don't want.

Q - what the best way to do this?

Comment: Just create a new project, put it where you want it.  Add existing files with Project + Add Existing item.  You can select more than one.

Comment: it's not clear what you are doing. Are you trying to move all files, including project to new directory?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio projects are simple XML files that can be edited. Just bulk replacing the paths in your favorite text editor is probably the easiest way to go (I do that all the time).

Comment: usually you don't need to change anything in the project file, unless the paths are hardwired, which is always a bad idea. Files are xml indeed, but when editing with text editor one needs to preserve the BOM. Also there are other relevant files, which must be moved, or some information will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project, without opening the existing one.
then copy all the header and the cpp files from the older folder to the new project folder.
'add existing item' will only point to the original file only.